# Validation_data for Autencoders in fit_generator

Tags: deep-learning, autoencoder

I'm trying to build an autoencoder, and I was wondering if I changed the validation_data from test_generator to train_generator again ?

The Keras documentation says this.

" This can be either

- a generator or a Sequence object for the validation data
- tuple (x_val, y_val)
- tuple (x_val, y_val, val_sample_weights)

on which to evaluate the loss and any model metrics at the end of each epoch. The model will not be trained on this data."

By changing validation_data to train_generator, shouldn't that decrease the loss and increase the accuracy?

I'm a newbie in autoencoders, I'm working on something big, and by the way accuracy is really bad (35%) is there I can Improve it ?

## Training the autoencoder

```
 # normalize the images and Data Augmentation.
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
```

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_path,
    target_size=(150,150),
    batch_size=100,
    class_mode='input',
    shuffle=True
   )

```
test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
test_path,
target_size=(150,150),
batch_size=32,
class_mode='input', 
shuffle=True)



#train the model   
autoencoder_train = autoencoder.fit_generator(
                        train_generator,
                        steps_per_epoch=32,
                        epochs=10,
                        validation_data=train_generator,
                        validation_steps=32,
                        shuffle=True)
```

I'm expecting an accuracy of 80% or more

Comment: Putting training data as validation data is not a good practice; you'll maybe increase your displayed validation accuracy but the goal of the validation is to simulate a small test on unseen data to see how your model is working in "reality". You should create a separate generator for validation that yield validation data.